# Маска текста в EditText  Android

Tags: android

Реализую некоторые поля для ввода. В Каждом из них есть подсказки, какой текст нужно вводить. 
Есть поле ММ/ГГ в котором символ "/" должен подставляться автоматически.

Создал адаптер содержащий интерфейс TextWatcher

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

       switch(editText.getId())
       {
       case R.id.addcardnumber:
           if(editText.getText().length() == 4||editText.getText().length() == 9||editText.getText().length() == 14){
                  editText.setText(editText.getText()+" ");
           }
           break;
       case R.id.addexpdate:
           if(editText.getText().length() == 2){
               editText.set 
               editText.setText(editText.getText()+"/");
           }
           break;

       }
```

Все работает. После ввода 2х символов в поле ММ/ГГ символ "/" подставляется, но курсор улетает на начало строки, и текст вводится с самого начала. 
Подскажите как это можно исправить?

И еще вопрос, можно сделать так что бы подсказки в поле для ввода, не исчезали как только  выбирается поле, а исчезали по мере ввода текста.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. чтобы поставить курсор в конец, используй метод **setSelection(text.size() - 1)**
2. чтобы подсказки исчезали по мере ввода текста, используй **hint**

Comment: hint скрывается сразу же после ввода текста

Comment: hint и используется.  Хочется что то было что то вроде этого https://www.portmone.com.ua/mts/uk/1/

Comment: Кстати спасибо. Этот вариант отлично подошел.) единственное что text.lengs().

Проблемы правда появляются при удалении текста.

Comment: пожалуйста. возможно я ошибся, всех функций сразу не упомнишь)